# What normalization rules flattening one-to-many violate?

Tags: database-design, normalization

I'm trying to better understand NF in a theoretical sense. The data I have *feels* wrong but I'm not sure if/how it violates normalization

**Example table:**

| product | inc_charger | inc_cable | inc_headphones |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 1 |

It's obvious that `inc_` columns don't belong in here as it will balloon the table in a real application, and introduce a lot of other issues. Instead, a O:M relation can be used to list accessories included with a given product:

| product | inc_accessory |
| --- | --- |
| A | charger |
| A | cable |
| C | charger |
| C | cable |
| C | headphones |

While I know the relationship shouldn't be flattened, like in the first table, I'm not sure if it actually violates NF, and if so which one.

Comment: What is your 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question? What is "flatten"? It & your other everyday terms are not used with NFs & normalization. If you want to know whether/how "if/how it violates normalization", where are you stuck applying a definition or following an algorithm?  But if you are not stuck on a specific point following a definition, process or presentation, why do you care what you notice or wonder? (Rhetorical.) Right now you are just asking for a textbook or Q&A to be rewritten with no clear description of what you don't understand. PS "feels" is not helpful.

Comment: There is nothing wrong per se with either design. Neither is got from the other by normalization or denormalization, those aren't involved here. Normalization to higher NFs replaces a table variable by others using its columns that natural join back to it. Normalization doesn't mean "good design". Where exactly are you, in what design method? PS What is "O:M?" zero-to-M? What is that? That base variable is, depending on the system/definition of cardinalities used, M:M or (0-or-M):M. PS This is a case of DB subtypes/inheritance. Moving data to column names & back is pivoting & unpivoting.

Comment: "to better understand NF in a theoretical sense" -- If you are having trouble there, move on.  NF is a textbook crutch to explain things that will become obvious after you have built and used a few databases.

Answer (score -1):

I care more about the performance than about NFness.

Having a column for each option becomes unwieldy unless such additions are very rare.

There is a third option -- the `SET` datatype allows up to 64 true/false settings -- at a significant savings in space.  Sometimes it is easier to use `INT` instead of `SET`.  Either way, the code is rather clumsy and cryptic.

Your example shows just 0 and 1.  Is that the only case?

If you do many-to-many, I recommend designing mapping schema thus:  [*Many-to-many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .

If you start with something like your second option, then see the [pivot-table] tag for discussions of how to turn the data into output like your fist option.